# Design issue in Other flag option popup

Tags: bug, design

[image]

**The linked question is exactly what my problem was but it is not having any solution still.**

In the above image we can see the `comment box` going out of the dialog box in every Stack Exchange Sites,when we click `other (needs ♦ moderator attention)` in flag section.

Comment: What browser? What OS? And versions please.

Comment: *Flagging this for moderator attention.* I'm not running into issues you have, so please provide info about your OS and stuff. Oh, as Oded said.

Comment: I took that screenshot from Firefox Linux Mint OS,and also checked the same in Chrome and safari same issue being visible .

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ The linked question is exactly what my problem was but it is not having any solution still.

Comment: but still... it was asked before and that question has a bit more repro targets... you can agree to the dupe...

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 37.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @dh47 You stated yourself "*The linked question is exactly what my problem was*" in which case this is by definition a dupe. You need to upvote the other question, comment and/or make an answer to point out any additional issues or notes. You can also start a bounty on the other question to get it some more attention

Comment: @James sorry but it is 1 month old.And yea I already upvoted.

Comment: @dh47 Thanks for the correction. Coffee levels must be low..